# Passing a file from client to Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to let users upload files to a central 'org' repository stored in a Firebase Storage bucket. Unfortunately I can't write the custom rule necessary to use the client SDK for all users to access their org documents, so I have to pass by the Firebase Cloud Functions to upload and download files.

When I want to upload a file from Cloud Functions, I have first to pass the file from the client to the Cloud Functions.

For now I have tried to pass the file in a simple object, but it obviously doesn't work.

```
// Client firebase clouf function 
const addFile = this.func.functions.httpsCallable('addFile');
const file = event.target.files[0];
addFile({file, meta, path})
.then( r => {
    resolve(r);
})
.catch( e => {
    resolve(e);
});

// in the cloud function when I perform
console.log(data.file);
// I receive a {} log...
```

Does anybody knows how to perform this?

**EDIT**

I finally decided to go this way:

1. setup a custom claim token when user access a specific view in which I need some group of files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
2. storing all files in a normal storage bucket and uploading/downloading them only when request.auth.token.customToken == uniqueBucketID

Comment: If you solved your own problem here on Stack Overflow, please answer your question with the solution (don't just edit the question with the solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to go this way:

setup a custom claim token when user access a specific view in which I need some group of files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

storing all files in a normal storage bucket and uploading/downloading them only when request.auth.token.customToken == uniqueBucketID